# Wifi connectivity error in Ubuntu 19.10!

Tags: 19.10

I'm using Asus Vivobook series. I updated to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04. I'm facing wifi connectivity error. No wifi connections appearing in selecting network area.

I googled about this error but i'm unable to solve this error.

Plus: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`
I used the above command, the output is

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The Wifi works on Windows, but not detected still now on Ubuntu 19.10

The output for `dmesg | grep iwl` is,

```
[   15.728691] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.432287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   16.432288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   16.432840] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   17.205672] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[   17.214378] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   17.214821] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   17.271719] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: d4:6d:6d:fd:88:2e
[   17.348161] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   17.478744] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   41.802017] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   47.016226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   47.150627] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   47.218014] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

Comment: @trvne Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, I can't edit my comment, I deleted it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated the question with the command and output.

Comment: All looks good there. Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output in the question. Do i have to re-install the Ubuntu 19.10 to overcome this error?

Comment: I don't see any error anywhere.

Comment: @Pilot6 If there is no error, i dont understand why my wifi is not connecting with my pc. Will my Wifi Router cause any problem? The model is TP-Link TL-WA901ND

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your help. I'm re-installing the Ubuntu 19.10 again!

Comment: @trvne The name of a Wireless Access Point can be hidden. Is your WAP set up with a hidden name?